# Trouble with color on c# console application

Tags: c#, colors

This program I have prints out a string at any given coordinates. It should contain some foreground and background color.I have an error that says Warning  1   The field  'ConsoleApplication1.ConsoleText.color' is never used
 Here is my code:

```
class ColoredText
    {
        public int x = 10;
        public int y = 20; // Coordinates
        public string Text = "Hello!";
        ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.Blue;

        public ColoredText(int x, int y, string Text)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = color;
            Console.BackgroundColor = color;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 0);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
        public virtual void Draw()
        {
            if (x >= 80 || y >= 49 || x < 0 || y < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Värdet är inte giltigt");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.Write(Text);
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }


    }
```

any ideas on whats wrong with the error?

Comment: Well the warning is telling you everything, you haven't used `color` that you defined `ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.Blue;` anywhere in your code

Comment: But if you look at my draw method, i have assigned the foreground and background color to the ConsoleColor.Blue wich is the value of color

Comment: yes, instead you can use `color` field, like: `Console.ForegroundColor = color;` or you can remove your field `color` from your code

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing *wrong* with the error, but it's a warning explaining that, although you define a variable named `color`, even though you set it, you never actually *use* it anywhere.

The fix this, use the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The field 'ConsoleApplication1.ConsoleText.color' is never used

This warning means you are having a color field in Class **ConsoleText** , and you have put the code for  class **ColoredText**.

You should check in that class, if you need to use to it to stop the warning.